# Is it necessary to generate sitemaps for old indexed urls?

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap

I have a web site with content from 2001 and I need to remake the sitemap. Question arises: if the old urls have already been indexed do I need to add them again (the same urls) to the sitemap even if not haven't changed?

for example:

the sitemap  have this url and is generate always from 2006
`http://www.semana.com/encuestas/encuesta/le-cree-encuestas-electorales/146255-3`

Is it necessary to generate it again if it's already indexed?

Comment: thanks for edit  my english is so  baaaaad @joosek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URLs are active and important from ranking perspective, it is better to have it in sitemap even if it is indexed already. It helps to provide metadata information like when page was last changed, how often it is changed etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the urls are active currently, you should add them to the new sitemap because it will help in gaining rankings.

You should add them to the new sitemap even if they already been indexed.